# Why does git checkout create a branch which tracks a remote branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have two branches on remote repo - master and development.

Now, after cloning the repository I was on the ONLY local branch named `master`. After `git checkout development`, this is the message I got:

> Branch development set up to track remote branch development from origin.
>   Switched to a new branch 'development'

How on earth could that be? I didn't specify the `-b` flag to create a new local branch. If I do `git checkout adasdasd` instead, I get `error: pathspec 'asdasdasd' did not match any file(s) known to git.`, which makes sense. But is it just some default git behaviour (creating a local branch if the name specified in checkout matches the remote branch)?

In short it looks like `git checkout development`, run for the first time, actually performed `git checkout -b development origin/development`.

Comment: Why would you ever want a local branch with the same name as a remote branch but that *doesn't* track the remote branch? There's already plenty of potential for confusion when you're using a version control system like `git`, why create more?

Comment: @Caleb because the remote branch is called something like `development` - a name it might be hard to avoid using? Bear in mind there could be hundreds of branches on several remotes which have names someone else wants to use locally.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you checkout a branch which exists as a remote, it assumes that you want to create a branch which tracks the remote branch.

From the docs:

> If  is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it <remote>) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to

```
$ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

This is obviously very useful much of the time - this is usually what people want to do. If you wanted your branch to be based on your current one, and not the remote tracking branch with the same name, or if there is a name collision, then it is annoying.

If you do `git checkout -b foo` this won't happen. Note if you don't already have a branch called `foo` this is what you want anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That simply means that the repository you cloned has the `development` branch on remote (GitHub).

When you cloned it, all the remote branches were cloned too. That's why `git checkout development` worked (switched you on the `development` branch).

If you find this unexpected, you can delete it from the remote:

```
git push origin --delete development
```

To push a branch on the remote do (you probably did this when you pushed your branch on GitHub):

```
git push origin development
# or 
git push --all # this will push all your branches
```

Comment: But when I do `git checkout master` and `git checkout development` again, the message I get this time is `Switched to branch development`. So it wasn't just a switch to existing branch, right? In short it looks like `git checkout development`, run for the first time, actually performed `git checkout -b development origin/development`.